# Element type "provider" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with my Manifest file? I'm getting the following error:

> Element type “provider” must be followed by either attribute specifications, “>” or “/>”

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="cypri.games"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".CyipsoidActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <provider android:name="MyContentProvider"  android:authorities="com.cypri.games" />

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say your parser is unhappy with XML namespaces (having a colon in the attribute name), or else there's some control character in the file that didn't transfer to your question.

Comment: Can you be a bit more pacific?

Comment: @Cyan: Is my answer somehow belligerent?

Comment: No sir. I am merely requesting more info.

Comment: [pacific](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pacific) is probably not what you meant.  Anyway, I can't help much more since I don't use android myself.  Try opening your file in a binary editor and make sure there aren't any special characters, like ASCII 26 (EOF, sometimes shown as ^Z), near the provider tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check menifest file if you have refacter provider class package than it will created some syntactical mistake.
just recheck your manifest file for provide syntex.